# VS 2010 C++ LNK2005 errors while using #pragma once and #ifndef

Tags: c++, lnk2005

```
1>Deck.obj : error LNK2005: "class Card card" (?card@@3VCard@@A) already defined in Card.obj
1>PokerTester.obj : error LNK2005: "class Card card" (?card@@3VCard@@A) already defined in Card.obj
1>PokerTester.obj : error LNK2005: "class Deck deck" (?deck@@3VDeck@@A) already defined in Deck.obj
1>C:\Dev\Poker\Debug\Poker.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I've learned why these errors occur by googling, but I don't know why they're still happening when I've tried #pragma once and the #ifndef protection thing.

Here's my Card.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
public:
    Card(int cardSuit = 0, int cardValue = 2); //constructor will create a two of hearts by default
    ~Card(void);
    int getSuit(); //returns the suit of the Card
    int getValue(); //returns the value of the Card
    int getColor(); //returns the color of the Card
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Card &cCard);

private:
    int suit; //card suit
    int value; //card value
    int color; //card color
} card;

#endif
```

and my Deck.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Deck
{
public:
     Deck(void);
    ~Deck(void);
    void newDeck(); //regenerates the full 52 card deck (e.g. cards are missing)
    void shuffle(); //shuffles the deck
    int cardsInDeck(); //returns the number of cards remaining in the deck
    Card takeTopCard(); //returns the top card and removes it from the deck
private:
    vector<Card> myDeck; //vector of 52 Card objects that make up the deck
} deck;

#endif
```

This is probably pretty obvious, but I just can't figure it out...

as requested, here's Card.cpp:

```
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card(int cardSuit, int cardValue)
{
card.suit = cardSuit;
card.value = cardValue;
if(cardSuit == 0 || cardSuit == 1) card.color = 0;
if(cardSuit == 2 || cardSuit == 3) card.color = 1;
}

//returns the card's color
int Card::getColor() 
{
return card.color;
}

//returns the card's suit
int Card::getSuit()
{
return card.suit;
}

//returns the card's value
int Card::getValue()
{
return card.value;
}
```

and here's the thing I wrote to test them:

```
#include "Deck.h"

int main() 
{
Deck testDeck = *new Deck();
Card testCardCreation = *new Card();
Card testCard = testDeck.takeTopCard();
testDeck.shuffle();
Card testShuf = testDeck.takeTopCard();
cout << testCard << endl << testShuf << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The objects `card` and `deck` are defined in the header. When you include the header into a translation unit it will create another definition of this object. You should probably just remove `card` and `deck` from the class definition. If you actually need these objects to be defined, you'd use

```
extern Card card;
```

Answer (score 2):

They are linker errors, they're not related to C++ code per se.

The problem is at the end of the definitions of Card and Deck. Why do you have:

```
} card;
```

And:

```
} deck;
```

?

Comment: I saw it done that way on an old C++ tutorial I found online. I haven't done any C++ since my first class on it last Spring and it fixed my errors. Dietmar gave me the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you defined "class Card" multiple times, you'd get a *compile* error, not a link error.

2) For the most part, your header files look fine.  In fact, you don't really need both: one or the other of #pragma once or #ifndef should suffice.

3) PROBLEM: leave off the final "card" and "deck" from your class definitions!